# How to enable anonymous authentication with custom account in IIS using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am able to enable anonymous authentication using powershell with the below command.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -PSPath IIS:\\Sites\\test1 -Name Enabled -Value True
```

But I also need to add custom account with username and password (test/test123) while enabling the anonymous authentication instead of the default user. Can anyone provide the command for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APPCMD.exe is the single command line tool for managing IIS 7 and above. [(source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

The tool is located in : C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

You can use it like this in PowerShell :

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
.\appcmd.exe set config "SiteName" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /enabled:"True" /commit:apphost
.\appcmd.exe set config "SiteName" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /userName:"IUSR" /commit:apphost
.\appcmd.exe set config "SiteName" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /password:"P@ssw0rd" /commit:apphost
```

Command detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication#appcmdexe).

Comment: Is this to enable anonymous authentication custom user and password?

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for Set-WebConfigurationProperty command

Comment: Did you try : 

Set-WebConfigurationProperty system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -Name username -value myuser

Set-WebConfigurationProperty system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -Name password -value mypassword

Don't forget to add your -PSPath

Comment: yeah that is working but not in single command

Comment: What do you mean ? Does ISE return an error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229047/discussion-between-powercat-and-smily).

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in powershell. However, each parameter of powershell only accepts one parameter. If you want to pass multiple parameters in one statement, it is more troublesome than executing three statements.

Or you can write the three statements into a script, and you can enable anonymous authentication and set up users at the same time by executing the script once.

1. Create a txt file and rename it to xxx.ps1. Type in following powershell command.

   ```
   Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "enabled" -value "True"
   Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "userName" -value "test"
   Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "password" -value "test123"
   ```
2. Open powershell and enter command.

> & 'D:\change.ps1'

Then it will work.